# JQuery UI: How to place the resize handle somewhere else in a container?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui, resize

Here is a small working example that demonstrates using JQuery UI to resize a (complex) container:

```js
$("#outer1").resizable({
    minHeight: 150,
    minWidth: 400,
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #808080;
  display: flex;
}

#outer1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border: 1px solid blue;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: rows;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#left1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border: 1px solid blue;

  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  height: auto;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#center1 {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  height: auto;
}

#bar1 {
  background-color: #c0c0ff;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

#right1 {
  background-color: #a0e0a0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="outer1" >
    <div id="left1" >
        <div id="center1">
            foo
        </div>
        <div id="bar1">
            bar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right1">
        x
    </div>
</div>
```

This displays a blue-grayish container with a green box attached to the right. A resizing handle is placed directly in the bottom right corner of the container.

Now: How can I place the resizing handle in the bottom right corner of the blue box in the container? If this handle is moved then the whole container should be resized. This way the green box would feel "attached" to the blue-grayish box and move together with the rest on resize.

Background: As a next step I'd like to set the container background to transparent and make the height of the green box smaller. This way it really would feel as the green box would be attached to the rest. Everything would technically still be a single `div` but to the user it would feel differently: The user would perceive the grayish-blue area as "the box". But for this approach the resize handle needs to be placed within the blueish box on the bottom of the container.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that using JQuery UI?

If it turns out that the JQuery UI cannot be used to implement this, how can this be achieved with a different approach?

Comment: can **$("#bar1").resizable({alsoResize: '#outer1'});** help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:

```
$("#left1").resizable({
    alsoResize: "#outer1"
});
```

Thank you @gaetanoM, you provided the crucial idea to the solution! Good thinking!